# array of pointers - how to store from one array of pointers to another

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 char *p[2];
 char *q[2];
 char *a = "Hello";
 char *b = "world";
 p[0] = a;
 p[1] = b;
 *q = *p;
 printf("\n %s \n",q[0]);
 printf("\n %s \n",q[1]);
 return 0;
}
```

I wanted to store the pointers stored in the p to q. when tried to print q[1], i'm getting a junk value. But q[0] prints "Hello" correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`*q = *p` is the same thing as `q[0] = p[0]`. That's why printing `q[0]` works but printing `q[1]` doesn't. If you want to copy all the pointers you'll need either a `for` loop or `memcpy()`.

```
memcpy(q, p, sizeof(p))
```

Comment: But I want to write the *p[2] into a file write(fd,p,size) is not possible;

Comment: `sizeof(p)` will return the size of `2`character pointers which will be `8`. If you wish to write both the strings to a file, you will have write them in a loop.

Comment: @Angus: Why would you want to write a *pointer* to a file? That's a serious mistake, because the pointer is meaningless to the file, and to future programs (including this program). Which book are you reading?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue I understand my statement is specific to a particular platform where `sizeof` of a character pointer is `4` which can't be guaranteed. I don't understand why you say my comment was wrong. Your point of `sizeof(char *)` being more than 4 is valid, but is very specific to certain systems.

Comment: @Ganesh: You don't even have to sit at a different computer, or a different OS to get different pointer sizes. In the past, `sizeof (char *)` has also been two, and can quite easily be all over again if you download one of those old compilers. At the current point in time, most 64-bit implementations will use 64-bit pointers. A 32-bit implementation will also run on 64-bit hardware. In which day and age are you programming where `sizeof (char *)` isn't more commonly 8?

Comment: @modifiablelvalue well i work on ARM which powers most of the latest handhelds and I have seen `sizeof(char *)` to be `4`. In my limited view, `64-bit` implementations are not very common and `32-bit` continues to be the norm. Even on my PC, where I am running MinGW,`gcc 4.6.2` whose default mode is `32-bit`. I feel unless someone is explicitly programming for `64-bit`, I feel the more commonly used mode is `32-bit`. Maybe my view of the world is limited :-)

Comment: @Ganesh Write programs to work today and in [the future](http://www.arm.com/about/newsroom/arm-launches-cortex-a50-series-the-worlds-most-energy-efficient-64-bit-processors.php), not just today, and you'll enjoy the benefit of not having to painfully adapt fidgety code in the future. I would suggest that your view of the world is out-dated. 64-bit implementations are all I have worked with on PCs for the last two years, and I have spent enough time ensuring programs are built to take full advantage of the hardware it runs on to be certain of this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26683/discussion-between-ganesh-and-modifiable-lvalue)

Comment: @Ganesh I have a better idea... If the resource I mentioned earlier along side [this resource](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_community:comp.lang.c:Portability_attitude) doesn't convince you to change your ways, then perhaps you could continue this discussion with comp.lang.c or ##C on freenode.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue thanks.. My ways are decided based on the real world as seen by my eyes. If required, I will take it up with comp.lang.c. While you ask other to mend their ways, probably you can also try to look at the world from a different perspective. Who knows you might see an entirely new picture

Answer (score 0):

The problem here like Kevin mentioned is that what you have is an array of pointers... so in order to accomplish what you want you need to memcpy the pointers over into the other array. This is because (these are example values mind you :)

```
p[0] = 0xaaa
p[1] = 0xbbb

*q == 0xaaa
```

so

```
q[0] = 0xaaa
```

q[1] is junk

So you are not copying the array, only a single value :)
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you want to do. You think you use " *q = *p; " to assign all pointers in p to q. But did you know that just assign p[0] to q[0], p and q are not pointers. They are just a array, you can't use this syntax to copy a whole array to another, but you can use memcpy or assign its elements one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish correctly, declare `q` as a double pointer `**q`, and assign it like this: `q = p`.